# SQL-subquery workaround to join based on alias

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Attempted Subquery using alias

```
SELECT
  *, 
  IQ.EndPart, 
  IQ.QtyToShip 
FROM
  parts p
  INNER JOIN (
     select
       *, 
       (case when c.kitno is null then l.partno else c.partno end) as [EndPart],
       (case when c.kitno is null then l.TotalQuantity else c.reqqty end) as [QtyToShip]
     FROM 
       shipments s
       INNER JOIN shipments_li l ON s.ShipmentNo = l.ShipmentNo 
       LEFT JOIN ProductConfiguration c ON l.PartNo = c.KitNo WHERE s.Status='N' and year(s.OrderDate)>2007
   ) IQ ON p.partno = IQ.EndPart
```

Looking for a way to join the parts table to my query below, using the part # which is aliased as EndPart. If there is another way to acheive the results of taking two columns and combining them instead of case and an alias that would be a great alternative as well.  All my searches of other individuals quest to achieve the same have yielded the result you cannot perform a join based on alias because the results have not been determined at that point, recommending a subquery as a workaround.  I'm just not sure how to acheive working results.  The above query was what I attempted to get working.  Any help appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Original Query

```
SELECT
  *, 
  (case when c.kitno is null then l.partno else c.partno end) as [EndPart],
  (case when c.kitno is null then l.TotalQuantity else c.reqqty end) as [QtyToShip]
FROM
  shipments s
  INNER JOIN shipments_li l ON s.ShipmentNo = l.ShipmentNo
  LEFT JOIN ProductConfiguration c ON l.PartNo = c.KitNo
WHERE
  s.Status='N'
  and year(s.OrderDate)>2007
order by s.shipmentno
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is there a reason you don't want to use a subquery?

Comment: Don't mind using sub query just can't seem to find the correct coding to get working. Receive a generic error so not sure what is misphrased

Answer (score 0):

More proper way

```
--- CREATE TempTable
DECLARE @tblTemp AS TABLE (EndPart INT,
                       QtyToShip INT)

INSERT INTO @tblTemp (EndPart, QtyToShip)
SELECT 
       (CASE WHEN c.kitno IS NULL 
             THEN l.partno ELSE c.partno END) AS [EndPart],
       (CASE WHEN c.kitno IS NULL 
            THEN l.TotalQuantity 
            ELSE c.reqqty END) AS [QtyToShip]
FROM dbo.Shipments s WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN shipments_li l WITH(NOLOCK) ON s.ShipmentNo = l.ShipmentNo 
LEFT JOIN ProductConfiguration c WITH(NOLOCK) ON l.PartNo = c.KitNo 
WHERE s.Status='N' AND YEAR(s.OrderDate)>2007

SELECT
   p.*, 
  tmp.EndPart, 
  tmp.QtyToShip 
FROM dbo.parts p WITH(NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN @tblTemp tmp ON  p.partno = tmp.EndPart
```

Comment: Can this be used in any environment like an excel SQL query? Can you explain a little about what the clauses are e.g nolock? Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Can this be performed in SQLserver with a readonly access or do you have to have full read write priveleges to create a temporary table?

Comment: I need to run this as one query, I am assuming this would be run as two queries